# Why does a requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout errors happens when executing (heavy?) code in ganache using web3py?

Tags: solidity, ganache, web3py

I'm trying to generate a sorted list of random `uint32` numbers. Generating the list is easily done:

```
for (uint24 i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
    seed = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(seed)));
    sorted[i] = uint32(seed);
}
```

where `limit` is an `uint24` indicating the number of samples, `seed` is an arbitrary `uint` and `sampled` is an `uint32[limit]`. However, if I try to generate a sorted array like this:

```
for (uint24 i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
    seed = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(seed)));
    sorted[i] = uint32(seed);

    uint24 j = i;
    while (sorted[j - 1] > sorted[j]) {
        (sorted[j - 1], sorted[j]) = (sorted[j], sorted[j - 1]);
        j--;

        if (j == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

then this yields the expected result for small values of `limit` (like 10), but `web3py` fails with the following error for bigger inputs (like 300) when I try to `call` the function associated with the previous code:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1371, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 280, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 447, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8545): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 957, in call
    return call_contract_function(
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1501, in call_contract_function
    return_data = web3.eth.call(
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 186, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 147, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/middleware/exception_retry_request.py", line 105, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/providers/rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/_utils/request.py", line 48, in make_post_request
    response = session.post(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/personal/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8545): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

I guess that Ganache is quite busy and that's why it can't answer fast enough for `web3py` to be satisfied, but the added code doesn't seem so heavy that it cannot be dealt with. Or do I miss something else that makes this code too heavy for Ganache?

Answer (score 2):

you can set timeout in your Web3py http provider:

```
Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(endpoint_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8545,request_kwargs={'timeout': 600})
```